# Retrieving a list of all file descriptors (files) that a process ever opened in linux

Tags: linux, file, file-io, process

I would like to be able to get a list of all of the file descriptors (now considering this question to pertain to actual files) that a process ever opened during the runtime of the process.  The problem with polling /proc/(PID)/fd/ is that you only get a snapshot in time of what is currently open.  Is there a way to force linux to keep this information around long enough to log it for the entire run of the process?

Comment: You should explain why do you ask this.

Comment: Are you sure you mean file descriptors? As @BasileStarynkevitch points out, they get recycled. For example, information that a program has had a file descriptor value 4 returned 1000 times having called open()/close() 1000 times doesn't sound useful. Do you mean the filenames?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch. So the original intent was to extract consumer/producer data from processes that are run in a makefile.  Constantly breaking dependencies become a headache in large projects and I wanted a way to get all of this without having to manually inspect each rule.

Comment: @bazza, You are correct in that I mean filenames  and shouldn't have used the term file descriptor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming specifically.  It should be on the Unix&Linux exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, notice that a file descriptor which is `open`-ed then `close`-d by the application is recycled by the kernel (a future `open` could give the same file descriptor). See [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Then, consider using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html); you'll be able to log all the syscalls (or perhaps just `open`, `socket`, `close`, `accept`,  ... that is the syscalls changing the file descriptor table). Of course `strace` is using the [ptrace(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) syscall  (which you probably don't want to bother using directly).

The simplest way would be to run `strace -o /tmp/mytrace.tr yourprog argments`... and to look, e.g. with some pager like `less`, into the quite big `/tmp/mytrace.tr` file.

<sup>As [Gearoid Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300745/gearoid-murphy) commented you could restrict the output of `strace` using e.g. `-e trace=file`.</sup>

BTW, to debug `Makefile`-s this is the wrong approach. Learn more about [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/).

Comment: strace -o strace.out -e trace=file yourprog argments

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch, this is a good solution although very brute force.  Just ran it on a perl script I was concerned about and it dumped more than enough information.  Any abbreviated solutions I will also be interested in because as you said. the logs can become quite large when dumping all system calls but will consider this the answer.